# Why are my columns appearing below each other instead of next?

Tags: html, angular, html-table, multiple-columns

As you can see from the bottom of my image, my products are appearing below each other. How do I make it so that they appear next to each other, on their own column?
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aeoG.png)

```
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<div *ngFor="let p of products">
    <th><b>{{ p.productLabel }}</b></th>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping over a `div` which is a `block` type HTML tag.
Put your `*ngFor` on a `th` instead.